# How to disable error message pop-ups in my electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I wrote an electron app that has to connect to a local server in order to work. Once the program starts, it tries to connect to the server using the Nodejs net library, if one second passes without it connecting to the server the program will try to connect again, once a connection to the server is established the program will continue as normal.

The issue I am having is when my client can't find, or connect, to the server on the network, I get a pop-up error message which I don't want to show.

The image below shows the error message I am receiving, I am using Ubuntu but I get the same message on windows:

[image]

And just for reference here is my relevant code:

main.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const ChatApp = express();

require('./backend/scripts/javascript/net_receiver.js');
require('./backend/scripts/javascript/websocket_receiver.js');

ChatApp.use(express.static('./frontend'));

ChatApp.listen(3003, function() 
{
    console.log('\nControl Panel Server Running on Port 3003');
});

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = true

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() 
{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
    {
        icon:               'frontend/chat_app/css/App_Logo.jpg',
        width:              700,
        height:             830,
        //autoHideMenuBar:  true,
        //fullscreen:       true,
        webPreferences: 
        {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3003");
    
    mainWindow.on("closed", function () 
    {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("resize", function (e, x, y) 
{
    mainWindow.setSize(x, y);
});

app.on("window-all-closed", function () 
{
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") 
    {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on("activate", function () 
{
    if (mainWindow === null) 
    {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

net_client_sender.js

```
const net       = require('net');
const client    = new net.Socket();
const settings  = require("../../settings/comms_settings.json");

netClient = {}

netClient.client = client;

netClient.ConnectToPLC = () =>
{
    client.connect(settings["modbusPORT"], settings["plcIPv4"]);
}

netClient.SendRequest = (msg) =>
{
    client.write(msg);
}

module.exports = netClient;
```

net_client_receiver.js

```
api         = require("./api.js");
netClient   = require("./net_client.js");

var connected = false;

/*Check if there is a connection to the PLC,*/ 
/*if not wait a moment and try to connect again*/
var CheckConnection = () =>
{
    /*if there is no connection to PLC*/
    var connectionTester = setInterval(() => 
    {
        if (connected === false)
        {
            console.log("Connection to PLC failed!");
            console.log("Retrying connection...\n\n");

            /*Retry connection to PLC*/
            netClient.ConnectToPLC();
        }
        /*if there is a connection to the PLC*/ 
        else
        {
            /*stop trying to connect to the PLC*/
            clearInterval(connectionTester);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

netClient.client.on("timeout", () => 
{
    connected = false;
    CheckConnection();
});

netClient.client.on("connect", () => 
{
    connected = true;
    api.StartMainLoop();
});

netClient.client.on("data", (data) => 
{
    api.ReadModbusMessage(data);
});

netClient.ConnectToPLC();
CheckConnection();
```

So just to clarify, I am not concerned with the error itself, but rather just with the fact that the error is shown in a pop-up message. So if someone can please tell me what to do to make it not show it would help a lot.

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't seem to produce the error. Please identify the relevant snippet and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, have you heard of `try/catch`? What have you tried so far, anyway?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks, I updated the question as you asked. As for the try-and-catch method, I tried it but I get the error message.

Comment: So you should be able to listen for an `"error"` event using `.on()` on your `netClient.client` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#socketconnect)). I'm not sure this will prevent the exception from being thrown though. If it does, I'm happy to expand on it and could add an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Initially this is what I did, it never initiated and the pop-up still showed.